# NSString leaking memory

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, memory-leaks, nsstring

I'm kinda new in finding memory leaks in objective c and how to fix them. I'm know how to use  alloc/init/copy and release/retain but ( a least i think so :-) ) but i have some strange memory leaks in my IOS app.

```
-(void) sendStats {

// read the app settings
plistHandler *readData  = [[plistHandler alloc] init];
[readData setPlistName:@"Settings"];
NSDictionary *settingsArray  = [readData readPlist];
[readData release];

NSNumberFormatter * f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
NSNumber * myNumber = [f numberFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [settingsArray objectForKey:@"range"]]];
[f release];

int rangeForUrl;

if(myNumber != nil) {
    rangeForUrl = [myNumber intValue];
} else {
    rangeForUrl = 10;
}

// get uniqe device ID
UIDevice *getdev = [UIDevice currentDevice];
NSString *uniqueIdentifier = [getdev uniqueIdentifier];

NSString *deviceId  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"IOS-%@", uniqueIdentifier];

// get the unix timestamp
NSDate * past = [NSDate date];
NSTimeInterval oldTime = [past timeIntervalSince1970]; 
NSString * unixTime = [[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%0.0f", oldTime] autorelease];


// send the data with a post request to the API
HttpRequest *data = [[HttpRequest alloc] init];
data.postData   = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"&device=%@&age=%@&gender=%@&latitude=%@&longitude=%@&timestamp=%@", deviceId, [settingsArray objectForKey:@"age"], [settingsArray objectForKey:@"gender"], @"00", @"00", unixTime];

data.controller = @"sendDevice";

NSString *url   = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www..eu/api/send_device"];

[data loadHostName:url];

[data release];

//NSLog(@"string s: %@", data.postData);

}
```

This is the memory leak according to Xcode instruments => leaks:

Leaked Object   #   Address Size    Responsible Library Responsible Frame
NSCFString,     0x16cb40    144 Bytes   Foundation  -[NSPlaceholderString initWithFormat:locale:arguments:]

This is the line with "data.postData = ..." in my code. Can someone help me out?

this is how I use postData in the class httpRequest:

```
- (void)loadHostName:(NSString *)hostName {



responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", hostName]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

if(authString) {
    [request setValue:authString forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
}

if([postData isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] && postData != @"") {

    NSData *dataToPost = [postData dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[dataToPost length]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Current-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:dataToPost];

}

NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[connection release];

}
```

with of course:

NSString *postData;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *postData;

and

@synthesize postData;

Comment: How did you declare `postData`?

Comment: postData is a NSString in the class httpRequest with @property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *postData and synthesize postData.

Comment: @Melvin Do you release `postData` in `dealloc`?

Comment: @albertamg Thnx, looks like its fixed now. But i dont really understand how the dealloc works. I never did a alloc/init on postData. Does this mean every object in my .h file like postData need to be released in the dealloc in the .m file? Anyone knows a good tutorial about this subject?

Comment: @Melvin I provided an answer. Check it out. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to release `postData` in `dealloc`.

> looks like its fixed now. But i dont really understand how the dealloc works. I never did a
>   alloc/init on postData. Does this mean every object in my .h file like
>   postData need to be released in the dealloc in the .m file?

Speaking of properties, you need to release in `dealloc` all your properties **not** marked `assign` (along with any non-property instance variable you own). Non-`assign` properties **own the object held by the backing instance variable** so you need to relinquish ownership of it by sending it a `release` message in dealloc.

From ["The Objective-C Programming Language"](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW16):

> Declared properties, along with the @synthesize directive, take the
>   place of accessor method declarations; when you synthesize a property,
>   the compiler creates accessor methods as needed. However, there is no
>   direct interaction between property declaration and the dealloc
>   method—properties are not automatically released for you. Declared
>   properties do, however, provide a useful way to cross-check the
>   implementation of your dealloc method: you can look for all the
>   property declarations in your header file and make sure that object
>   properties not marked assign are released, and those marked assign are
>   not released.

I would also recommend you to read the ["Memory Management Programming Guide"](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000011-SW1).